# How do I fetch embeddable document from a value field of a MongoDB and Cosmos DB?

Tags: java, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

How do I fetch embeddable document (small part of a larger JSON stored) from a value field of MongoDB and Cosmos DB?

If I want to store data in MongoDB in a {key,value} way where key is student roll number and value is the complete data structure of Student Object in JSON format.

For Example below is the Value stored in MongoDB for Key RollNumber of Student

```html
{
  "name": "Rahul",
  "class": 12,
  "marks": {
    "maths": 45,
    "bio": 56,
    "chemistry": 76,
    "practicals": {
      "bio": 20,
      "chemistry": 25,
      "phy": 30
    }
  },
  "address": {
    "city": "bangalore",
    "per": {
      "adminUserId": 25,
      "name": "Rahul Gupta",
      "admin": false,
      "active": true,
      "email": "Rahul.Gupta@mail.com"
    }
  }
}
```

From above value, I want to fetch only "Marks" or "practicals" JSON from the full document to avoid network load of transferring full document from MongoDB to Client.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.yourcollection.find({name:"Rahul"},{marks:1})
```

should do. As you see in MongoDB , you can specify criteria as well as fields that you want to retrieve. 
For more options check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)

Comment: key is 100000 (which is rollnumber), I want to fetch only practicals node for key 100000

Answer (score 0):

you can write below query

```
db.student.aggregate([
{ $match : {'name': "Rahul" }},
{ $project :{"marks":1} }
])
```